# DocuSign jwt access token renewal

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

I created docusign jwt access token for my application manually/php sdk with consent and used that access token in the code for restapi. Expiry of access token is 1 hr. How to renew the DocuSign jwt access token without asking consent again and again? Or how to prolong the expiry of access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call request_jwt_user_token again and get the token from the response. You dont need to request consent again. Have a look at the recommended best practices [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-best-practice/)

Comment: Is this function automatically update jwt access token or we need to write condition to check  the expiry and access token (saved in db table ) and if needed we have to call this function again  right ??